# I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when MaxConcurrentOperationCount > 1

Tags: objective-c, iphone, exc-bad-access, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Hello i am using NSOperationQueue to download images in the background. I have created a custom NSOperation to download the images. I put the images in table cells. The problem is if I do [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: 10] and i scroll down several cells the program crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Every time it crashes at the same place in the table. There are 3 cells one after the other which are for the same company and have the same logo so basically it should download the images 3 times. Every other time it works fine.

```
- (void) main
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.imageURL];
    debugLog(@"downloading image: %@", self.imageURL);
    //NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [url release];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    [data release];
    if (image)
    {
        if (image.size.width != ICONWIDTH && image.size.height != ICONHEIGHT)
        {
            UIImage *resizedImage;
            CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(ICONWIDTH, ICONHEIGHT);

                        //!!! UIGraphicsBeginImageContext NOT THREAD SAFE
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
            CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
            [image drawInRect:imageRect];
            resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            self.theImage = resizedImage;
        }
        else
        {
            self.theImage = image;
        }
        [image release];
    }
    [delegate didFinishDownloadingImage: self];
    [pool release];
}
```

This is how i handle downloading the images. If i comment out 

`[delegate didFinishDownloadingImage: self];`

in the function above it doesn't crash but of course it is useless.

```
-(void) didFinishDownloadingImage:(ImageDownloadOperation *) imageDownloader
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(handleDidFinishDownloadingImage:) withObject: imageDownloader waitUntilDone: FALSE];
}

-(void) handleDidFinishDownloadingImage:(ImageDownloadOperation *)imageDownloadOperation
{
    NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    CompanyImgDownloaderState *stateObject = (CompanyImgDownloaderState *)[imageDownloadOperation stateObject];

    if ([visiblePaths containsObject: stateObject.indexPath])
    {
        //debugLog(@"didFinishDownloadingImage %@ %@", imageDownloader.theImage);

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: stateObject.indexPath];
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag: 1];
        if (imageDownloadOperation.theImage)
        {
            imageView.image = imageDownloadOperation.theImage;
            stateObject.company.icon = imageDownloadOperation.theImage;
        }
        else
        {
            imageView.image = [(TestWebServiceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] getCylexIcon];
            stateObject.company.icon = [(TestWebServiceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] getCylexIcon];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should always inspect the stack trace where your app crashes **first**. If you are lucky, it will provide a clear indication of what you're doing wrong. Can you post that part of a crash log along with the relevant code?

Comment: There are approximately 6 threads there at the moment of crashing. I don't know at what stack trace to look. I thought that dealloc is called for the operation before i have a chance to do anything with the image but after placing an nslog there i found out it isn't called at all... i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Right now it's not a big deal if it doesn't work because i had a working version without using nsoperation and operationqueue, and i probably will use that one; but i was just curious because i had no idea what is wrong. I tried this one because it was shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this mailing list post, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` isn't thread safe.  The post hints that `CGBitmapContextCreate` and related functions are the safe way to do it.

http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2009-10/msg00035.html

Comment: Yes it seems that was the problem. I used a @synchronized directive to make the image drawing part thread safe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're crashing because you're trying to access cells in the tableview that are not there.

Regardless of how long the logical table is, the visual tableview only holds enough cells to display the section of the logical table currently on screen. At the default row size, a table shows and therefore contains, only 9 to 10 cell objects. For example, if you have a logical table that is 100 rows long and your view is showing rows 11-20 the table only has 9 cell objects. If you show rows 89-98, it only has ***the exact same*** 9 cell objects. No matter which rows you display, you see the same 9 cell objects over and over again. The only thing that changes is the data they display.

If you try to access the cell for a logical row off screen, you won't get anything back. In your case, you try to access the 11th logical row but there is no 11th cell and there never will be.

I think you have some conceptual confusion because you're trying to store data in the tableview itself by setting the cell contents. This will not work because tableviews do not  store any data beyond what is immediately displayed. When a tableview needs to display more rows as you scroll, it reuses the existing cell and its DataSource delegate changes the data that the existing cells display.

Instead of storing the images in the cells, you need to create a data model and store the images there. Then when the tableview scrolls, it will send `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to its datasource delegate. The datasource delegate will then ask the data model for the data for the logical row, populate the reused cell and return it to the tableview.

Comment: Yes i know, there are only as much cells allocated in memory as there are cell visible at once on the screen. But i verified that in handleDidFinishDownloadingImage. First i verify if the cell is visible. And if it's visible then i change the image in the cell. Otherwise i change only in the data source so that next time when it scrolls into view the image will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems it is solved thanks to [codewarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300850/codewarrior). This is the part that changed.

```
@synchronized(delegate)
{
    UIImage *resizedImage;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.theImage = resizedImage; 
}
```